# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole raises HttpUnhandledException. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, httpcontext, httpunhandledexception

While I was working on my localhost it worked flawlessly.

However, when I deployed the application to another server it started to raise an exception.

Basically, this is the instruction that causes the Exception:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(*roleName*)
```

where *roleName* is a string representing the different roles in the application.

Exception fired:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
```

**Update**: This is how the user is being authenticated.

```
protected void LoginControl_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (!Page.IsValid) return;

    if (MyAuthenticate(LoginControl.UserName, LoginControl.Password))
    {
        if (LoginControl.RememberMeSet == true)
        {
            createCookie(LoginControl.UserName, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["idcustomer"]), true);
        }
        else
        {
            createCookie(LoginControl.UserName, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["idcustomer"]), false);
        }
        e.Authenticated = true;
        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(LoginControl.UserName, true));
    }
    else
    {
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
```

If it is related to the user authentication, what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**: Thanks to all. I have just done a Remote Debugging and realize this is the actual error:

[image]

Now, this is the situation: the User was authenticated in the login page. So, I think it is not a problem with the connection to the DB. Otherwise, the User wouldn't have been able to pass the login page to the MasterPage (where this error is being raised).

What can I be missing? Thanks again,

Comment: what is the `InnerException`?

Comment: Please see the Update to the question. Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to create the mysql_aspnet_membership provider by granting full trust through the machine.config and autogenerating the schema, instead of manually creating the membership tables in the database, which I though there could have been a valid way to create the db.

Afterwards, this didn't break anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Wild stab in the dark but the inner exception is probably a null reference exception being caused by the fact the user is not authenticated on the server so HttpContext.Current.User is null.  I would bet it is just that windows integrated authentication is not enabled on the live web server or a similar authentication setup issue.

Comment: OK from your code i see you are using forms authentication, is forms authentication supported/enabled on your server?  What happens when you try to log in?

Comment: Ok. How can I check whether it is supported/enabled in the server?

Comment: That authentication in the login page is done successfully. The problem is when loading the master page and asks for: HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(roleName)

Comment: I have just followed this post to enable Forms Authentication in the server: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771077(WS.10).aspx, but I keep getting the same error

Comment: I made a wild guess that HttpContext.Current.User is null and that you are getting a null ref exception, why don't you try confirming/refuting those things first.

Comment: You're right, there is a problem with the User. Please, have a look at the Update in the question